# CUDA (nested?) memory allocation

Tags: memory-management, cuda, nested, malloc, gpu

I am optimizing some code using CUDA. I am not sure if I should use cudaMalloc inside _ _ global _ _ function (fun1) or not (isn't x already allocated on GPU's memory?):

```
__global__ void fun2(double *y)
{
    int i=blockIdx.x;
    y[i]=...;
}

__global__ void fun1(double *x)
{
    //should I cudaMalloc() y for fun2 or just use the x which was already allocated in main?
    fun2<<<N,1>(x);
    ...
}

int main(){
    double *x;
    ...
    cudaMalloc((void**)&x, N*sizeof(double));
    fun1<<<N,1>>>(x);
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can't call cudaMalloc in device code. And I'm not sure you can call global function inside another global function either. You can only if you have  3.5 generation GPU.

Comment: So I can't optimise functions which include another function?

Comment: Describe your problem, please

Comment: In the code above, I have two functions (fun1,fun2) which I'd like to CUDA-optimize. Since I can't call fun2 from fun1 I don't see a way to use CUDA in both functions. Or am I wrong (probably, but don't know how to implement)?

Comment: You're not going to get much performance out of the machine if you're calling kernels with only one thread per block: `fun1<<<N,1>>>(x);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you mean something like this:

```
 __device__ void fun2(double *y)
    {
      int i=blockIdx.x;
      y[i]=...;
}

__global__ void fun1(double *x)
{

    fun2(x);
    ...
}

int main(){
    double *x;
    ...
    cudaMalloc((void**)&x, N*sizeof(double));
    fun1<<<N,1>>>(x);
    ...
}
```

But it's common to calculate threadId in global function

Comment: YES this seems legit! The thing that's not yet clear to me is when calling fun2 (from fun1), how does the compiler know how big is the array? To clarify, fun2 is actually a CUDA-optimised for-loop. If it was a global function, you could say tell size of the array using `fun2<<<SIZE,1>>>(x)`.

Comment: __global__ functions run on gpu. You allocates mamory with cudaMalloc((void**)&x, N*sizeof(double)); And you should call fun2<<<1,SIZE>>> instead

Comment: Yes; but how many times will fun2 be called in your code? It should be called SIZE-times (array size).

Comment: Exactly. fun1<<<1,N>>> - here you tell that you want to create 1 block with N threads. Each thread begins to excecute fun1. in fun2 you get i with i=(blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x . i ranges from 0 to N-1.